# Disallow DTD's while evaluating xpath

Tags: xpath, saxon

I have below code to evaluate xpath expression.

```
String inputXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM   \"test.dtd\"><Request><Header><Version>1.0</Version></Header></Request>";

String xpath="/Request/Header/Version";

XPathFactory xpf = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl();
final InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(inputXml));
String version = xpf.newXPath().evaluate(xpath, is);
```

`xpf.newXPath().evaluate` throws error as `test.dtd couldn't be found`. I want to disallow DTD completely. I have been reading about setting SAXParser feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" but not sure how to apply in this case or is there any other way to disallow/ignore DTD's.

Comment: You might get more response if you tag your question with saxon as this appears to be a Saxon configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. If you want this to fail because there is a DTD referenced, then you already seem to be achieving that.

However, if you want to set a property on the XML parser, there are two ways you could achieve it:

(a) Supply a SAXSource rather than an InputSource; initialize the XMLReader in the SAXSource to the XML parser you want to use, and use the XMLReader's setFeature interface to configure it before you pass it to the XPath engine.

(b) Set the Saxon configuration feature `http://saxon.sf.net/feature/parserFeature?uri=http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl` (that's a single string with no spaces or newlines) to the value true. You can do this using

```
xpf.getConfiguration().setConfigurationProperty(featureName, true);
```